# How can I draw this shape in drawable

Tags: android, drawable

Can someone guide me how to draw this shape in one drawable

[image]

Comment: Please show your source code that has issue drawing the shape.

Comment: I don't have any issue and I don't know how to draw that

Comment: @user12033682 Feel free to accept my answer if it's helpful for you and if it's  perfect compare to other answers. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="70dp" />
            <solid android:color="#E6C03131" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
            android:bottom="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:left="20dp"
            android:right="20dp"
            android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="70dp" />
            <solid android:color="#DCC45353" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:left="@dimen/_41sdp"
        android:right="@dimen/_41sdp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_100sdp" />
            <solid android:color="#DC00FF00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:left="@dimen/_55sdp"
        android:right="@dimen/_55sdp"
        android:top="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_100sdp" />
            <solid android:color="#DC00FF00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

in @Nilesh's answer there is not rounded corners and also color is not match with your requirements.

Comment: Correct the padding of the outer shape to remove the clipping effect. It would make your answer perfect.